# Is there a way to render span tags in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to highlight specific letters of the users input in a [textarea](/questions/tagged/textarea) using [span](/questions/tagged/span). However, when I used my script, instead of highlighting the letters, the [span](/questions/tagged/span) tags were just displayed as plain text and not rendered.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        span {
            background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="p"></textarea>

    <script>
         let toBeHighlighted = ['a', 'P', 'k'];

        document.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
            const input = document.getElementById('p');
            const letters = input.value.split('');
            const mapped = letters.map(word => toBeHighlighted.includes(word) ? `<span class="highlight">${word}</span>` : word);
            dtag.innerHTML = input.join('');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried the same script, but instead of the textarea using a normal paragraph with text, and it worked perfectly. Is there even a way of rendering [span](/questions/tagged/span) tags inside a [textarea](/questions/tagged/textarea)?
I have an alternative approach of just using a paragraph, where the users input will be displayed, but I really don´t want to use that and instead have the highlighted letters be highlighted in the texarea.

Comment: No, you can't. You can look into using "contenteditable" on a `<div>` or other container.